# How to get the corresponding key and value from the object and convert it to an array object

Tags: javascript

**I have referred to this article, but not what I wanted**. [convert object keys and values to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501142/convert-object-keys-and-values-to-an-array-of-objects)

I have the following data：

```
var test = {
  apple1:"a",
  apple2: "b",
  apple3: "c",
  v1r:'1',
  v2r:'2',
  v3r:'3',
  v4r:'4',
  a1:'5'
}
```

My attempts：

```
var keys = Object.keys(test);
var result =  keys.reduce((cur,item)=>{
   if(/^\d+$/.test(item)){
     let obj = {}
     obj[item] = test[item]
   }
   return cur
},[])
```

It's not what I wanted.

**The results I expect are as follows:**

```
let result = [{apple1:'a',v1r:'1',a1:'5'},{apple2:'b',v2r:'2'},{apple3:'c',v3r:'3'},{v4r:'4'},]
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have any specific rules on properties belonging together? How do you know `apple1`and `v1r` belong together.

Comment: @derpirscher hi,It is attributed with numbers

Comment: what will happen if there is a key by name `v12r` or `v23r`

Comment: @brk Thanks for the comment, Regenerate into a new object

Comment: @brk hi, I edited the question again, please have a look again

Comment: The question is not very clear since there is no clear sequences but this might help you.

Object.entries(test).map(([key,val])=>{
console.log(key) //do something with each key
console.log(value) //do something with each value
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very basic (and very generic) approach is just checking if there is a number in the property and then add the value to an object at the respective index. Of course, this will probably lead to undesired results, if the property names don't follow the rules

```js
var test = {
  apple1:"a",
  apple2: "b",
  apple3: "c",
  v1r:'1',
  v2r:'2',
  v3r:'3',
  v4r:'4',
  a1:'5'
}
let a = [];
for (let p of Object.keys(test)) {
  let m = p.match(/(\d+)/);
  if (!m) continue;
  var e = a[+m[1]] || {};
  e[p]  = test[p];
  a[+m[1]] = e;
}

a = a.filter(x => !!x)

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I need. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This will fail if the key is `v2errf1:'6'`

Comment: @brk What do you mean by *fail*? It will group that property together with `apple2` and `v2r`

Comment: why it will group with `apple2` and `v2r`

Comment: because it groups by the first number it finds ... Which, from the example seems pretty much, what OP wants ...

Comment: Well i think that is assumption but it is not mentioned anywhere. Why it shouldn't be a new key ?

Comment: Unless there is any more specification, one can draw whatever conclusion one wants from that example. You may have deduced other rules. But that doesn't mean, my approach is *failing*, unless OP specifies the rules. In favour of Occam's razor, I decided to assume a very simple rule: There is only one number within the property's name. And if there are more than one, take the first one ... If you ask "why shouldn't it be a new key" I can ask "why should it" ...

Answer (score 0):

Steps for each iteration (using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))

1. Get the number from the key
2. Get the object from the array with the same index as the number
3. If the object doesn't exist, create it and add it to the array
4. Add the key and the value to the array

After the `reduce` call you can use `.filter(Boolean)` to remove any empty values created by gaps in the numbers in the keys

```js
var test = {
  apple1: "a",
  apple2: "b",
  apple3: "c",
  v1r: "1",
  v2r: "2",
  v3r: "3",
  x9y1: false
};

var result = Object.entries(test).reduce(function(result, [key, value]) {
  // Get the number (step 1)
  var index = /(\d+)[^\d]*$/.exec(key);
  if (!index || !index[1]) return result;
  index = +index[1];
  // Get the object from the array (step 2)
  var item = result[index];
  // Add it if it doesn't exist (step 3)
  if (!item) result[index] = item = {};
  // Add the key and the value (step 4)
  item[key] = value;
  return result;
}, []).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Edit: if you want to get the last number in the key instead of the first, you can use this regex `/(\d+)[^\d]*$/` instead, you will also have to change the index, since you will be accessing the first matched group `(\d+)` instead of the whole regex match.

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao I'm glad I could help, I've edited the question so that if there are more than 1 numbers in the key, it only reads the last (I assume that's what you wanted)